# Create heap dump if memory usage exceed given threshold

Tags: java, jvm, out-of-memory

Is there any way to create heap dump when JVM memory consumption exceeds given threshold of MB?

Can we somehow achieve it by adding additional flags to java command, or using some external library to run together with java process, or maybe we need to write some code which will perform such action?

Comment: Sure, there are ways, e.g. running an OS process that checks memory consumption and triggers a dump (look at the command line tools available to your JVM, like `jstat`, `jmap`, `jcmd` etc.). Another option would be to use JMX to connect from a remote application or even use a local thread that periodically checks memory usage (e.g. using the methods in `Runtime`) and triggers the heap dump using the `HotSpotDiagnostic` class (if available in your JVM).